# Windows Integrated Security in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, security, windows-authentication

I have a .Net 4.0 WCF service hosted in a Windows service using Transport Security over a net.tcp binding. There were plenty of good examples of how to set this up. What I am looking for now are examples of authorizing users in this scheme.

We are assuming that this service will be part of a system that is all on one domain with Active Directory. Is there any advantage to doing claims-based authorization using ADFS rather than Windows Integrated security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx):

> AD FS is a standards-based service that allows the secure sharing of
>   identity information between trusted business partners (known as a
>   federation) **across an extranet**.

You do not need ADFS of you are all in one domain. Do not over complicate design unless you really need it. Stay with Windows Integrated security.